# How can I compare two properties which are different child types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework with SQL Server, I have types like the following:

```
public abstract record BaseType(string Raw);
public record ChildOne(string Raw) : BaseType(Raw);
public record ChildTwo(string Raw) : BaseType(Raw);

public class ClassOne {
    public ChildOne ChildOne {get; set;}
}

public class ClassTwo {
    public ChildTwo ChildTwo {get; set;}
}

public class BaseTypePair {
    public BaseType Left {get; set;}
    public BaseType Right {get; set;}
}

// Converters
public class BaseTypeConverter : ValueConverter<BaseType, string> {...}
public class ChildOneConverter : ValueConverter<ChildOne, string> {...}
public class ChildTwoConverter : ValueConverter<ChildTwo, string> {...}
```

In the database context I have `DbSet<ClassOne>`, `DbSet<ClassTwo>`, and `DbSet<BaseTypePair>` properties.

Now I want to join them like so:

```
context
    .BaseTypePairs
    .Join(context.ClassOnes,
          baseTypePair => baseTypePair.Left,
          classOne => classOne.ChildOne,
          (baseTypePair, classOne) => classOne)
    .ToList() // Something to actually run the Queryable
```

which should be converted to something like

```sql
select ClassOne.*
from BaseTypePairs
join ClassOne on BaseTypePairs.Left = ClassOne.ChildOne
```

And that SQL query works perfectly since `Left` and `ChildOne` are both just strings.

But the LINQ always gives a warning and then throws an exception.

Warning: `Possible unintended use of method 'Equals' for arguments 'baseTypePair.Left' and 'classOne.classOne.ChildOne' of different types in a query. This comparison will always return false.`. And that kind of makes sense, except if you were to do the join in C# (in-memory) it would work correctly.

Exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: Unhandled expression '[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlConstantExpression]' of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SqlConstantExpression' encountered in 'SqlNullabilityProcessor'.`

#### Also tried

- to cast `ChildOne` up to `BaseType` like `(BaseType)classOne.ChildOne` in the `join` but then the query throws an exception saying that it can't convert the LINQ query to SQL.
- to use `ChildOne.Raw` and `BaseType.Raw` in the `join`, but the query still throws saying it can't create the SQL query.
- to use `.Where(...Any)` like `context.ClassOnes.Where(classOne => context.TypePairs.Any(typePair => typePair.Left == classOne.Id))` and **this works**! The generated SQL is slightly different in that it uses `... where exists (select ...` instead of a `join`. But I can't tell any performance difference, and even the execution plans look nearly identitcal. I guess this is sort of a solution, but I would rather be able to use the `Join` method as it's closer to the intent of the code.